# Запустить скрипт Python нажатием кнопки из Excel

Tags: python, excel

Возникла необходимость периодически обновлять данные в ячейках таблицы Excel. Сам алгоритм перерасчета тяжелый и основан на ML-модели, уложенного в скрипт Python. Но использовать его будут пользователи, далекие от мира программирования, поэтому необходимо сделать так, чтобы обновление (то есть отработку самого скрипта) возможно было запустить нажатием обычной кнопки на этом же листе Excel. Для понимания прикладываю то, чего нужно добиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии кнопки "Обновить" должен запускаться заранее разработанный скрипт Python, который, в конечном счете, обновит значения всех ячеек таблицы.

Возникли очень большие сложности с тем, как реализовать данную идею, а в интернете ничего более-менее понятно изложенного я не нашел.
помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную задачу.
Для облегчения понимания предположим, что:

- скрипт Python лежит в папке с путем "С:\folder_script"
- название скрипта "script"
- эксель-файл лежит в папке с путем "С:\folder_table"
- название скрипта "table"

Уже очень долго не могу сделать ничего толкового. Заранее благодарен)))

Comment: не уверен, что питону микрософт позволит писать в открытый файл. видимо, надо делать макрос, если он позволяет, то стартовать оттуда питон и заполнять результатом лист

Comment: Я прописал в скрипте питона, чтобы он закрывал открытый файл самостоятельно, если он открыт, забивал туда новые значения, а затем вновь открывал. Так что с этим проблем возникнуть, вроде как е должно

Answer (score 0):

[Описание необходимых действий](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=message&FID=5&TID=141023&TITLE_SEO=141023-udobnoe-vnedrenie-yazyka-programmirovaniya-_python_-v-fayl-excel-na-osnove-portativnoy-sborki-python&MID=1141249&buf_fid=1&tags=%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%98#message1141249)
Но все эти действия необходимо проводить на каждом компьютере, где Вы хотите настроить такую интеграцию. Это конечно значительно сужает область применения. Но более простого способа я не нашел (когда мне необходимо было решить подобную задачу). Либо, как вариант скомпилировать .py в .exe, а на кнопку прикрутить vba скрипт типа:

```
Sub Primer1()
Dim myTest
    myTest = Shell("""С:\folder_script\my_python_script.exe""", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: Нет, это будет всего один файл на общем сервере. Действия всегда будут проводиться только для него и только на одной машине.

Comment: Ну, в таком случае Вы свободны в выборе инструмента :) Проще IMHO скомпилировать скрипт в exe. Потому что наворачивание на excel не всегда стабильно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Для примера сделал простенькую модель.

1. `main.py`: создает фрейм из массива случайных чисел, записывает в `.csv` и ждет 2 секунды, имитируя длительные вычисления.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь',
     'Декабрь'], columns=['Месяц'])
df[[f'Column_{i}' for i in range(1, 4)]] = np.random.random(12 * 3).reshape(12, 3)
df.to_csv(r'c:\test\random_data.csv', decimal=',', sep=';', encoding='windows-1251')
time.sleep(2)
```

2. Книга Excel, где на Лист2 импортированы данные из этого `.csv` через "Данные / Из текстового/ CSV файла" / Загрузить:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Также на этом листе есть кнопка "Обновить данные", которой назначен макрос `RefreshData()`, который с помощью `WshShell.Exec()` запускает и мониторит процесс выполнения python скрипта. По завершении скрипта обновляет ту самую таблицу на Лист2:

```
Sub RefreshData()
    py_script_path = """C:\Users\Alex20\PycharmProjects\test\main.py"""
    py_exe_path = """c:\Users\Alex20\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe"""
    
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec(py_exe_path & " " & py_script_path)
    Do
        Status = WshExec.Status
        Debug.Print "status - " & Status
        If Status = 1 Then Exit Do
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист2").ListObjects(1).Refresh ' обновляем таблицу по завершении подготовки данных
End Sub
```

Из небольших неудобств - черное консольное окно на время выполнения соотв. скрипта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]